# Angular dynamic flag icon in span based on mat-select change

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, ngmodel, mat-select

I have a mat-select and I would like to **change a flag icon in a span in the mat-label**, based on the selected option.

The initial flag is shown, after a click no change occurs in the span.

The flags in the option list are working correctly, so the question only concerns the **label**.

I am trying something like:

HTML:

```html
    <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>
      <span [class]="getLanguageFlag(selectedLanguage)"></span>
      {{ selectedLanguage }}
    </mat-label>

    <mat-select
      [(ngModel)]="selectedLanguage"
      name="selectedLanguage"
      id="selectedLanguage"
    >

      <mat-option
        *ngFor="let language of languages"
        [value]="language"
        (click)="changeLanguage(language)"
      >

        <span [class]="getLanguageFlag(language)"></span>
        {{ language }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

TS:

```js
    selectedLanguage: string = environment.defaultLanguage;

    constructor(
    private store: Store<State>,
    private translateService: TranslateService) {}

    changeLanguage(language: string): void {
    this.selectedLanguage = language;
    }

    getLanguageFlag(language: string): string {
    let style = 'flag-icon flag-icon-';
    return language === 'en' ? `${style}gb` : `${style}${language}`;
    }
```

I've also tried a getter/setter, but the setter didn't seem to work when using the mat-select.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What library are you using for flags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested it and you code works. You should just check if 2-letter country code is correct.

I don't know if you just didn't copy it correctly, but you are missing closing `<mat-form-field>` tag in you HTML, so check that also.

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-responsive-yvkfxc?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks for the help! Wow, really stupid... the text was not visible due to the toolbar having a fixed height

Comment: Welcome. Consider upvoting and accepting my answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

The final solution, based on Nenad's help:
(the flag before the option, no label above the select input)

```
<mat-form-field>
<span [class]="getLanguageFlag(selectedLanguage)"></span>
&nbsp;
<mat-select
  [(ngModel)]="selectedLanguage"
  name="selectedLanguage"
  id="selectedLanguage"
>
  <mat-option
    *ngFor="let language of languages"
    [value]="language"
    (click)="changeLanguage(language)"
  >
    <span [class]="getLanguageFlag(language)"></span>
    {{ language.toUpperCase() }}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```